# Make part of the text as link- Next.JS and Material UI

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I wan to make some part of the text as link,using Next.Js and Material UI
Like this-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Link component of Material UI which allows you to do have the part of the text as link
https://material-ui.com/components/links/

Comment: you can mark it as answer , would help others too.